# Video capture to not show in my gallery on phone

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-media-plugin

I am using ng-cordova's plugin capture to capture (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) videos inside of the ionic framework from a mobile phone.

```
$scope.captureVideo = function() {
var options = { limit: 1, duration: 10 };

    $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData) {
        var i, path, len;
        for (i = 0, len = videoData.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            path = videoData[i].fullPath;
            console.log("Path of the video is = " + path.toString());
        }
    }, function(err) {
        // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
    });
}
```

The problem is every video capture I take saves to my phones gallery which I do not want. If I capture an image it does NOT save to my phone's gallery which is what I would like with video capture. Is there a way to stop videos from being saved?

> I tried deleting the file but apparently the video file is not saved
>   in cordovafile directories.

```
function DeleteFile() {

var filename = "20161024_095758.mp4";
var relativeFilePath = "file:/storage/C8F0-1207/DCIM/Camera";
console.log('data directory: '+cordova.file.dataDirectory);
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(relativeFilePath, function(dir) {
dir.getFile(filename, {create:false}, function(fileEntry) {
              fileEntry.remove(function(){
                alert('file removed');
                  // The file has been removed succesfully
              },function(error){
                alert('error'+JSON.stringify(error));
                  // Error deleting the file
              },function(){
                alert('file doesnt exist');
                 // The file doesn't exist
              });
  });
});
```

**The code above to delete file results in Error Code:6. No modification allowed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently **WE CANNOT DELETE AND WRITE FILES FROM MICRO SD-CARD SINCE VERSION 4.4. It is read only now.**. And, when the user deletes the file from the gallery, it would not be available for the project. Here is what i came up with.

I copied the video file to cordova's external directory from where i could read the file when wanted and delete as per the need. Plugins required are `cordova-file-plugin`  and `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`

```
.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaCapture,$sce,$cordovaFile, $cordovaFileTransfer, $timeout) {
       $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(videoData[0]));
            console.log(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory);
             $cordovaFileTransfer.download(videoData[0].fullPath, cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + 'my-video.mp4', {}, true).then(
                                function(result)
                                {
                                    console.log('success: '+ result);
                                },
                                function (error)
                                {
                                    console.log('error: '+ JSON.stringify(error));
                                },function (progress) {
                                    $timeout(function () {
                                      $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
                                    });
                                  },false);
               $scope.clipSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(videoData[0].fullPath);
               //$scope.videoSrc = videoData[0].fullPath;
        }, function(err) {
          alert('Err: <br />'+ JSON.stringify(videoData));
        });

  //delete the file according to filename.

    $scope.deleteVideo= function(){
        $cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, "my-video.mp4")
          .then(function (result) {
            console.log('Success: deleting videoData file' + JSON.stringify(result));
          }, function (err) {
            console.log('Error: deleting videoData file' + JSON.stringify(err));
          });
      }

})
```

Comment: Does this solution still work?  I am having the same issue and using your code It looks like it deletes the file successfully but it still appears in my gallery.  If you are just copying the file to another location and deleting it wouldn't the original file still exist and be uploaded to the gallery?

Comment: @MatTaNg, the problem that i faced was not being able to delete the file from the project itself. It remains that the file stays on the gallery, but i am referencing the file from the cordova directory itself to show and to delete. So, that when the users goes to gallery and delete it, it still remains for the project

Comment: Oh okay, I am not familiar with cordova file plugin.  Would I beable to use the removeFile function to delete videos off the gallery for my issue?

Comment: @MatTaNg, no you can't buddy.  WE CANNOT DELETE AND WRITE FILES FROM MICRO SD-CARD SINCE VERSION 4.4. It is read only now. That is why you need to copy the file within the project

Comment: I upload the video to a db anyway but I don't want my users to have a bunch of 10s video clips in their gallery.  There is no way to stop a video from being saved to the gallery and there is no way to delete the video from the gallery once it is saved there?